# Upgrading php in mamp breaks apache

Tags: php, macos, apache

I have `OSX Mavericks`, with `MAMP, apache2.2.27 and php5.2.17, php5.4.10`. Normally, I switch between these php versions and it works perfectly fine.

Now I downloaded `php5.4.34` from MAMP site and extracted to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.34` directory. It has similar structures to other php versions. I also changed the name of another php version to `_php5.4.10`. MAMP now presents `php5.4.34` in select options.

Now, it works fine with `php5.2.17`. But my Problem is when I try to change this to `php5.4.34`, apache wont start and generates SIGTERM error.

```
[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Following line is added automatically by MAMP to `httpd.conf`, which I presume is fine.

```
LoadModule php5_module   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.34/modules/libphp5.so
```

I cannot find missing link for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I tried deleting the previous php versions that you don't need and install fresh version of `PHP`. The problem was solved. It might be because it is trying to access renamed php installation by old name.

Comment: Yes, I have already solved the problem with the method you have shown. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Same here under MAMP 2.0.5 and osx 10.7.5

Strange because i changed the php versions in Mamp when I installed mamp

What I did:

I added a  5.3.14 php version to bin/php

prepended a php5.5.9 with 'x_'

In MAMP changed the php version from 5.3.6 to 5.3.14 and

My console says:

[Fri Jan 08 16:22:26 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 **PHP/5.3.6 configured** -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 08 16:22:36 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

So something somewhere still thinks 5.3.6 is used